# "Login Forbidden" when using Meteor's Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(func)

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a basic Meteor method that I am trying to call whenever the user attempts to sign in.

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (options) {
   Meteor.call('method', true, function (error, result) { 
     // do nothing
  });
});
```

However, whenever I try to sign in, I receive "Login Forbidden" as an error. The same happens upon sign up. I am guessing I need to be returning something for the function, but do not know what. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

From the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt

`A validate login callback must return a truthy value for the login to proceed.`

In the block do some validations like if user is verified or not and return true or false to complete the login process.