# Understanding Accounts.validateLoginAttempt

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to build a login portal with accounts-password.  I have the registration working properly, where users are being created with custom fields in their profile.

I am running into an issue where once I try to log in with the created user, i am getting a Login Forbidden error.  I understand that I need to do validation and return a truthy value based on ["Login Forbidden" when using Meteor's Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(func)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585752/login-forbidden-when-using-meteors-accounts-validateloginattemptfunc), but even when doing something like the following is still giving me an error

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (options) {
  return true
});
```

Is there any examples on how to build a login validation function with basic information?  I think I can work with my custom fields after that but a starting point would be great.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For some reason removing accounts-base did the trick.  Not 100% sure why